# DirectX 12 Updating the Descriptor Heap

Tags: directx, directx-12

I'm currently writing my own graphics framework for DirectX12 (I've already written several DirectX 11 frameworks for personal game engines), and I'm currently [trying to copy the methods used in the recent Hitman game](http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc2016/Presentations/meyer_jonas_rendering_hitman_with.pdf) for resource binding.

I'm confused about the best way to handle per-object resource binding for the SRV/CBV/UAV heap. I've watched several GDC presentations, and they all seem to gloss over this.

Only 1 SRV/CBV/UAV heap can be bound at a time, and switching the currently-bound heap in the middle of a command list can be bad for performance on some hardware by forcing a flush. Because of this, what is the best way to handle updating the heap with new descriptors? To me, it seems like each command list would:

1. Get a hold of a SRV/CBV/UAV heap for itself.
2. For each object in a subset of objects, create descriptors on the heap pointing to per-object data that was placed into a separate upload heap.
3. Afterwards, another command list takes this filled descriptor heap and binds it, then issues draw calls mixed with `SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable` in order to move through the current descriptor heap.

This being said, several sources online ([including another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37310493/3239130)) suggest using one large SRV/CBV/UAV heap and copying into it using CPU-visible heaps. I'm assuming they're not attempting to use the asynchronous `CopyDescriptors`, but rather `CopyBufferRegion`. I tried using `CopyBufferRegion` to update data per-object, but to me this seems under-performant with so many transitions between `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_VERTEX_AND_CONSTANT_BUFFER` and `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST`. Am I misunderstanding something? Any clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to take a look at both [MiniEngine](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/MiniEngine) and [DirectX Tool Kit for DirectX 12](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK12) for some example code for approaches to dealing with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CopyDescriptors` is not asynchronous, it is a CPU operation that is immediate on the CPU. It can happen anytime before a command list is executed for volatile descriptor ( after the command list operation using it is recorded ), or have to be ready at the usage for static descriptor ( root signature 1.1 ).

The usual approach is to have a large descriptor heap, keep a portion for static descriptors, then use the rest as a ring buffer, allocating descriptor table offset on demand to copy and use the needed descriptor for any draw/compute operation.

`CopyBufferRegion` has nothing to do here, remember that mapping buffers is also an immediate operation, so you also ring buffer a big chunk of memory for your per objet constant buffers, and you cycle into it. The only thing is that you need to make sure you do not overwrite memory or descriptor while they may still be in use, so you have to fence to prevent the case.

Comment: So if I use `CopyDescriptors`, when does it update the heap on the GPU-side? When I call `SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable`?

Comment: No, CopyDescriptors is immediate, Once it returns, the copy is done. The only tricky thing is with root signature 1.0 versus 1.1. 1.0 and volatile table do not assume the descriptor are ready when you use them on the CPU, they assume they will be here when you close the command list. 1.1 with static table assume the descriptor are ready when when you set them to trigger a draw and that they will not change after that.

Comment: So if I'm rendering multiple objects, each with unique cbuffer data, I'd call `CopyDescriptors` to update the descriptor heap at a different offset for each object?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you walk the heap as a big ring buffer, allocating table on demands for your render operations, as the descriptors have to survive until the gpu will be done with them.

Comment: That CPU stall on `CopyDescriptors` seems like it would be insanely expensive, opening/closing the pipe to the GPU once per object. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: There is no stall, because there is no sync here, it is not a gpu copy, it is merely a cpu memcpy from a cpu adress range to a gpu adress range. You cannot do faster than that.

Comment: So then after I do this CPU-copy, when will the GPU-side heap memory be updated? Sorry if this is a dumb question!

Comment: What do you not understand in the word immediate, after the call to CopyDescriptors, it is ready, it is IMMEDIATE !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133482/discussion-between-cehnehdeh-and-galop1n).